# Can I create a car that powered by sound energy?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, air

If I create a car that has an ideal loudspeaker (that can emit sound with any positive real number of amplitude) on car roof then loudspeaker emit very very loud sound (sound may be complex or be pulse which has specific rhythm) , can this car move ?

I know that electromagnetic has momentum but I don't know that sound really hasn't momentum or it has ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with Ryan's answer. A source of sound can cause [acoustic streaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_streaming), which is a net flow of ambient fluid away from the source. See this [demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkoHYD3CDo0). Therefore a source of sound experiences a back-thrust which can be utilised for propulsion, although it would likely be inefficient.

The picture of a vibrating medium, with no mean flow, which extends forever is correct only if the medium is non-dissipative, but any real fluid is dissipative. This gives rise to an effective body-force on the fluid given by the averaged quantity $\nabla\cdot\overline{\rho\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}}$, in which $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity field with zero mean corresponding to pure vibration.

Answer (score 3):

No, a car with a speaker attached will not be propelled forwards. Sound waves are longitudinal waves and do not carry mass with them as they propagate and therefore do not have any momentum. The diagram below shows how longitudinal waves can send a vibration through a material without carrying any mass. Look at the red dots, they have no net movement and therefore the sound wave has no net momentum. [image: Sound waves propagating through air]

The most that would happen to your car is that it would vibrate backwards and forwards as the speaker extends and retracts.

Comment: Interesting. But vibration can generate energy, right?

Comment: Is it possible if sound isn't simple ,for example, if gray wall move right very fast but move left very slow?

Comment: Sure. If you had wheels that would only turn forwards then I think the car would go forwards because the car would be pushed forwards by the speaker extending and then wouldn't be able to be pulled backwards by the speaker retracting.

Comment: Unfortunately moving the wall back slowly won't help as it will still result in the same energy transferred to the car. The only way I can think of making it work is to lock the wheels while the grey wall moves left. I suppose if you moved the grey wall slow enough the friction in the axle of the wheel would be high enough to stop the car from being pulled backwards.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if I lock the wheels while the grey wall moves left but I think I might be possible if I don't do that. If grey wall move like when hummingbird flutter their wing but much faster with less distance, is it still impossible ?